# filtrar datos en el datagridview que ya esten cargados c#

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

actualmente tengo una grilla que se llena automaticamente al abrir el formulario,
pero al escribir en el txt (codigo del extintor) necesito que se filtre en la grilla dependiendo del id_extintor con los datos ya cargados en la grilla (sin conexion a la base de datos).

al cargar la grilla primero genero el dataset, luego el datatable lo que quiero lograr es filtrar el datagridview con los datos que ya están en él para evitar una sobrecarga de ida y vuelta hacia el servidor, cada ves que escribo un numero.

actualmente cargo la grilla en una clase y la llamo al abrir el formulario.

```
private void cargar()
{
     grillas grilla = new grillas();
     grilla.llenargrillaextintorsincliente(grilla_cliente);
}

// 
public void llenargrillaextintorsincliente(DataGridView grillaparticular)
{
      try
      {
           //ejecuta sentencia sql y abre conexion
           int asignado = 2;
           int estado = 1;
           MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select a.id_extintor,a.rut_cliente,a.fecha_recarga,a.fecha_vencimiento as vencimiento,b.descripcion_kilo as kilo,c.descripcion_tipo as tipo,d.descripcion_estado as estado,e.descripcion_asignado as asignado from tb_extintores a INNER JOIN tb_kilos_extintor b ON a.id_kilo = b.id_kilo INNER JOIN tb_tipo_extintor c ON a.id_tipo = c.id_tipo INNER JOIN tb_estado d ON a.id_estado = d.id_estado INNER JOIN tb_extintor_asignado e ON a.id_asignado = e.id_asignado where a.id_asignado = '" + asignado + "' AND a.id_estado ='"+estado+"'", conexion.obtenerConexion());

            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);
            // devuelve la los datos a la grilla
            grillaparticular.DataSource = dt;

       }
       catch (Exception f)
       {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
       }
       finally
       {
            // con.Close();
            conexion.obtenerConexion().Close();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puede funcionarte es poner el dataTable como variable publica para que después de haberlo llenado lo puedas consultar directamente cada que necesites y no tengas necesidad de estar realizando peticiones a la base de datos

```
public  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
public void llenargrillaextintorsincliente(DataGridView grillaparticular)
{
  try
  {
       //ejecuta sentencia sql y abre conexion
       int asignado = 2;
       int estado = 1;
       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select a.id_extintor,a.rut_cliente,a.fecha_recarga,a.fecha_vencimiento as vencimiento,b.descripcion_kilo as kilo,c.descripcion_tipo as tipo,d.descripcion_estado as estado,e.descripcion_asignado as asignado from tb_extintores a INNER JOIN tb_kilos_extintor b ON a.id_kilo = b.id_kilo INNER JOIN tb_tipo_extintor c ON a.id_tipo = c.id_tipo INNER JOIN tb_estado d ON a.id_estado = d.id_estado INNER JOIN tb_extintor_asignado e ON a.id_asignado = e.id_asignado where a.id_asignado = '" + asignado + "' AND a.id_estado ='"+estado+"'", conexion.obtenerConexion());

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);


        da.Fill(dt);
        // devuelve la los datos a la grilla
        grillaparticular.DataSource = dt;

   }
   catch (Exception f)
   {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
   }
   finally
   {
        // con.Close();
        conexion.obtenerConexion().Close();
   }
}
```

Metodo para filtar (para el filtrado puse como ejemplo el evento click de un boton pero puedes ocupar el evento que mas te convenga):

```
private void Filtrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           var lst = dt.Select(string.format("id_extintor = '{0}'",txt_buscar_extintor.Text);

           //Declaras un nuevo dataTable para asignarlo a grid y no afectar el original
           var table = new DataTable();
           var column = new DataColumn();
           //Agregas las columnas correspondientes al nuevo dataTable
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            column.ColumnName = "id_extintor";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            column.ColumnName = "rut_cliente";
            table.Columns.Add(column);
            .
            .
            .

            //LLenas el dataTable con el resultado de la busqueda
            foreach (DataRow row in lst)
            {
                table.ImportRow(row);
            }
           //Asignas el nuevo dataTable al grid
          grillaparticular.DataSource = table;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola yo logre hacerlo así:

- El datagrid ya tiene datasource desde un store proc.
- El % es por que es incremental la búsqueda.
- La variable filterfield representa la columna que estoy filtrando

```
private void Txt_Nombreprocesobusqueda_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filterField = "Nombre";
    ((DataTable)dgvProcesos.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'", filterField, Txt_Nombreprocesobusqueda.Text);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) de los dataTables

```
DataRow[] result = dt.Select("id_extintor = '" + txt_buscar_extintor.Text + "'");
```

Comment: me habia equivocado. habia puesto el metodo de carga de otra grilla =(

Comment: mi idea es llenar la grilla y despues en un textBox1_TextChanged filtrar la grilla.

Comment: pero programaticamente no se como realizarlo.

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas sencilla de filtrar un `DataGridView` cargado desde un `DataTable` es aplicar el filtro a la `DefaultView` del `DataTable` usando la propiedad `Filter`. En tu caso, dependiendo de cuando quieras filtrarlo, el código sería el siguiente:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ((DataTable)grillaparticular.DataSource).DefaultView
                                         .RowFilter = "id_extintor=" + textBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: ((DataTable)grillaparticular.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "id_extintor=" + textBox1.Text;   funciona pero tambien necesito que al borrar el txt vuelva a cargar la grilla como estaba.

Comment: Simplemente pon RowFilter=""

Comment: pero al borrar me da el siguiente error=  Información adicional: Error de sintaxis: falta el operando después del operador '='.

Comment: Intenta con `((DataTable)grillaparticular.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = ""` o `((DataTable)grillaparticular.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = null`

Comment: ((DataTable)grilla_cliente.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter ="[id_extintor]="+textBox1.Text; intente encerrarlo entre [] pero a los 30 segundos vuelve a dar al error pero los si los filtra.

Comment: try  { foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in grilla_cliente.Rows){String strFila = Row.Index.ToString(); string Valor = Convert.ToString(Row.Cells["codigo"].Value);
    
                        if (Valor == this.txt_codigo.Text)
((DataTable)grilla_cliente.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "[codigo]=" + txt_codigo.Text;
                        }
                        else
   {      ((DataTable)grilla_cliente.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = ""; } } }  catch(Exception f) { }

Comment: El codigo del filtro no tiene que estar dentro de ningun bucle! Sacalo fuera del `foreach`. Y como te dije,los corchetes no son necesarios

Comment: lo encerre todo dentro de un try catch y cree un foreach ademas de un if para cuando valor de la tabla sea igual a txt_codigo 1000 mil gracias me sirvio de mucho su respuesta.

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirviera