# Error No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView al abrir formulario

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Quiero filtrar un datagridview desde un control combobox, pero estoy recibiendo el siguiente error:

***No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView to a known managed provider native type.***

Antes de agregar el método para filtrar el dgv, el combobox cargaba los datos correctamente agregue el método para filtrar el dgv y me arroja este error, el campo mostrado en el combo es de tipo texto pero el value member es de tipo entero en la base de datos.

Ya intente pasar el parametro como int pero no me funciono, entonces se cual puede ser el error, estos son mis métodos:

//Evento Load para llenado del combobox

```
SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString());

    private void FormMachine_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       string query = "SELECT Idmachine, machine_model FROM Machine";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnx);
        try
        {
            cnx.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            cnx.Close();
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "machine_model";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Idmachine";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

//Metodo para filtrar el dgv:

```
     private void loadDGV()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Machine";
        query += " WHERE Idmachine = @Idmachine";
        query += " OR ISNULL(@Idmachine, '')=''";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnx);

        try
        {
            cnx.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idmachine",comboBox1. );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idmachine",comboBox1.SelectedValue);
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            cnx.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

//Llamado del metodo anterior en el combobox

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        loadDGV();

    }
```

El error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco de antemano cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Saludos

DS

Comment: es un error de redacción o en tu consulta pasas todo tu comboBox1.

Comment: Una disculpa corregi la consulta @EduardoJaramilloLicea

Comment: yo me refería aquí `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idmachine",comboBox1. );`

Comment: No entiendo bien a que te refieres, pero en el combo solo cargo el Idmachine y machine_model.
Entonces en base al Id selecionado en el combo quiere pasar todo el select del metodo loadDGV al dgv. @EduardoJaramilloLicea

Comment: Es que le estas pasando todo el combo, deberías pasar únicamente tu SelectedValue

Comment: O ya lo intente con SelectValue y Text y me obtenia error tambien lo intente asi:
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Idmachine",int.Parse(comboBox1.Text))
@EduardoJaramilloLicea

Comment: Edite la pregunta tambine paso el SelectValue y me tira error.
@EduardoJaramilloLicea

Comment: [Esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/111990/182188) ofrecen soluciones para filtrar un `DataGridView` que te pueden ahorrar muchas lecturas a la base de datos.